# How to add styles while hovering mouse on a dynamically added thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
var data = [{
  src: "..",
  title: "Image 1"
}, {
  src: "..",
  title: "Image 2"
}, {
  src: "..",
  title: "Image 3"
}];


$(document).ready(function() {
  var $thumbs = $(".thumbnails");

  // dynamically add thumbnails to page
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $thumbs.append('<a href="#" class="thumbnail" alt="' + data[i].title + '"><img src="' + data[i].src + '" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>');
  }
});
```

```html
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="bootstrap.js@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <!--thumbnail section-->
  <section class="container">
    <div class="row add-bottom text-center thumbnails">
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
```

I want to apply opacity and some text while hovering mouse on an image thumbnail for the given code as shown in the image below.How would I go for doing the same?[image: opac]

Answer (score 0):

.thumbnail span {

```
opacity:0;

z-index:0;

position:absolute;

top:50%
```

}

.thumbnail span:hover {
    opacity:1;

```
z-index:1;

 position:absolute;

top:50%

-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out .0s;

transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out .0s;

color:red
```

}

Add a span in  tag

Comment: I have tried adding span earlier,but I have not got desired result.Can you please share your code for which you have got the required output?